# Is it acceptable to use "blog" to describe a blog post?

Tags: nouns, terminology, internet

I've seen people, including people who write for a living, say they wrote "a blog" about this or that topic, when they obviously mean a specific post.

I find this incredibly grating. Dictionaries don't seem to include this sense, which leads me to think this is a misuse of the language.

On the other hand, blog is a portmanteau of web and log, and one could (I think) use log to refer to a specific entry in a record.

Comment: Usually when people say they wrote a *blog*, that actually stands for *blog post*, so I guess some people say *blog* meaning *post*

Comment: These days blog is also a **verb** so they could very well say **I blogged about this today** when in fact they mean they *wrote a blog post about it today*.

Comment: I don't have a problem with using blog as a verb, but using it to mean a blog post didn't seem right. Anyway, if it's good enough for these dictionaries it's obvious I'm the one who should get with the times. :) @Josh61, if you will write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of blog meaning a blog post is actually in dictionaries and it appears it is common usage:

> - [Blog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blog): a Web site that contains online personal reflections, comments, and often hyperlinks provided by the writer; also : ***the contents of such a site***. 
>     (M-W)
> - [Blog](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blog): 1)a website containing a writer's or group of writers' own experiences, 2) ***single entry or post on such a website***: *She regularly contributes a blog to the magazine's*.  (Dictionary.com)

Comment: First definition (from M-W) "the contents of such a site" does not seem to refer to a single post, but rather a collection of posts (just like "contents" does not refer to a countable item either). The second definition does.